# How to set the value of a text box with javascript on an ASP.NET webform

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

so in a form I have the following control:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="monthlyAmount" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

The ClientIDMode Static is because a master page is in use.

I then have this Button:

```
<input type="button" id="calculate" onclick="AutoFillEstimate()" value="Calculate Estimate" />
```

Wired to this Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AutoFillEstimate() {
        document.getElementById("monthlyAmount").nodeValue = "test";
    }
</script>
```

I feel like I'm just using nodeValue instead of what I should be using, but I have no idea where to look for reference on these things.

Answer (score 13):

If I understand you correctly, you are just trying to set the value, just use:

```
document.getElementById("monthlyAmount").value = "test";
```

Comment: You mean in visual studio? There isn't a whole lot of support for intellisense with javascript, I wouldn't rely on it at all.

Comment: Honestly, depending on what you're doing.. I would use Stackoverflow or google...

Comment: @Firoso Mozilla has a very good reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript

Comment: This won't work. The id of the asp control is not the id you give it. The id represents the hierarchy of controls. You want to use Client ID property.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do this is:

```
document.getElementById("<%= monthlyAmount.ClientID %>").value = "test";
```